# How to display customer name for every transaction with total price is higher than average price?

Tags: sql, subquery, average

I want to display customer name if the total price is higher than the average price from every transaction. But the error message is "Column 'x.average' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." and I don't know where the problems are.

Here's my code

```
SELECT  c.CustomerId,
        hs.TransactionId,
        c.CustomerName,
        SUM(t.Price) AS [Total Price]
FROM MsCustomer c JOIN HeaderSalonServices hs
ON c.CustomerId = hs.CustomerId
JOIN DetailSalonServices ds
ON ds.TransactionId = hs.TransactionId
JOIN MsTreatment t
ON t.TreatmentId = ds.TreatmentId,
(SELECT AVG(Price) AS average
 FROM MsTreatment) AS x
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, hs.TransactionId, c.CustomerName
HAVING SUM(t.Price) > average
```

Comment: average is only defined inside the subquery, but just use your renamed "x". ;-)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your subquery to the HAVING clause:

```sql
SELECT  c.CustomerId,
        hs.TransactionId,
        c.CustomerName,
        SUM(t.Price) AS [Total Price]
FROM MsCustomer c JOIN HeaderSalonServices hs
ON c.CustomerId = hs.CustomerId
JOIN DetailSalonServices ds
ON ds.TransactionId = hs.TransactionId
JOIN MsTreatment t
ON t.TreatmentId = ds.TreatmentId
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, hs.TransactionId, c.CustomerName
HAVING SUM(t.Price) > (SELECT AVG(Price) AS average FROM MsTreatment)
```